# how to extract dates and make a +/- of 30 days to check a parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I need to find how to extract a date

then make a statement using between

:date is an input from the user

```
select userID,:date,reportid
from usertable
where userID = '120429'
and 
:date between (:date-30 days) and (:date +30 days)
```

Comment: `...and  :date between...` ,  `:date` or `column between` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [date/time arithmetic operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

```
:date + interval '30 days'
```

or

```
:date - interval '30 days'
```